# Exception thrown: 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll on large file upload ASP.Net core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, iis-7

I'm trying to upload a folder of size 543 MB using IIS express server and ASP.NET core backend. The upload is initiated by an ajax call. If I split the folder into 100 MB chunks and upload these 100 MB chunks from the front-end everything works fine. But as pointed out here [Can we split big ajax calls into multiple smaller calls to load data faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60787145/can-we-split-big-ajax-calls-into-multiple-smaller-calls-to-load-data-faster) splitting and making multiple calls has no evident advantage and might end up being a liability.

So now I'm trying to upload the folder as one ajax call. The problem is that the upload starts and I can see it progressing in the progress bar but after like 30% upload I get a Http Status code 500 from the server.

The server gives the following error:
`Exception thrown: 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll`

From what I understand this issue is related to file size limits imposed by IIS and ASP.NET core. To remedy this I have added the following code to my solution but no success.

**UploadController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(1073741824)]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 1073741824)]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync(){
await Request.ReadFormAsync();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Request.Form.Files.Count);
return Ok("Files uploaded.");
}
```

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <!-- Handle requests up to 2 GB -->
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**StartUp.cs**

```
 services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options => { options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null; });
 services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => 
            { options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 2147483648;
                options.ValueLengthLimit = 1073741824;
                options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = 1073741824;
               
            });

            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
            });
```

The startup file has other configurations of course but these are what I added to solve this issue.
Thanks for the help in advance!!
**PS** : Let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the [RequestFormLimits] attribute on top of the Upload() action as shown below:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 2147483648)]
public IActionResult Upload()
{
  ...
}
```

More information you can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62555240/13336642.

Comment: I did try this.... but no effect at all. Also the StartUp.cs has that as a FormOptions setting already.

Comment: Is your project on iis express or is it deployed to iis?

Comment: my project is on iis express.